# loading Module mod_rewrite on httpd.conf file causes "Forbidden" error on localhost

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, localhost

Im on a mac running Sierra 10.12.2 and apache 2.4.23

I set up a localhost environment and a virtualhost for the domain cumsa.mx and installed wordpress on it. Without getting too into detail now, some changes were made on Git that modified the wp permalinks, and hence the .htaccess file through wp.

I went to my main httpd.conf file and told it to load the module mod_rewrite as suggested by a colleague since that was necessary to be able to modify the htaccess file. Regardless of that, activating this module results in my local environment for cumsa.mx to become "Forbidden".

Can anyone think of any idea why this wouldbe the case or which permissions I need to modify and how? Thanks!

Comment: What dose the log file tell you? What is the content of your htaccess file?

Comment: I managed to fix it by looking at the error log file and it said that "FollowSymLinks was disabled, so as per my colleague's suggestion i edited the htaccess file manually and added this line to the top:

Options +FollowSymLinks

After I did that, I still had to change the ownership of some files, but more specifically, in regards to git, i had to use sudo, which was the key to GIT being able to edit the files. Thanks for your comment though man!